# iOS - Cancel bluetooth connection when app in background

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I have an iOS app connecting to a peripheral over BLE. I'm able to cancel the connection immediately when the app enters the background, or leave the connection active until iOS suspends the app.

Is there a programmatic way to keep the connection active for a brief period, but ensure it disconnect within a certain time - say after 60 seconds - to minimize battery impact and make the peripheral available for other iOS devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to get the BLE connection working in the background, request for background mode by adding the following key to your info.plist: `Required background modes` (array). Add `App communicates using CoreBluetooth` item to this array.

Second, in the AppDelegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground` fire a timer logic that calls a method which implements `[CBCentralManager cancelPeripheralConnection]`

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I find that iOS fires the command only when the app is registered for data notifications from the peripheral. Also, I'm calling [CBCentralManager cancelPeripheralConnection] to disconnect.

Comment: Updated answer with "cancelPeripheralConnection"