# Swift : How to disconnect BLE devices in background if application is in background for 30 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

My BLE device remains connected with the application when I put my application in the background.

I want to disconnect BLE communication if my application will be in the background for more than x seconds. (Example : x = 60 seconds)

I have tried to use Timer but it gives me an event when I came back to the foreground. I want to disconnect the BLE when the application is in the background.

Please let me know if anyone has faced & solved this expectation.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314215/ios-cancel-bluetooth-connection-when-app-in-background

Comment: @KishanBhatiya No, this solution disconnects the BLE immediately when the app went to the background. I want to disconnect only after user stays in the background for X second. And also i want to fire the method when the application is in background. (Not when it come back to foreground)

Comment: You could try using a `Timer` along with `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)`

Comment: @Paulw11 by using beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:) you can not be sure that method will fire on specific X Time. That method will call once OS will free & allow to fire.

Comment: No, beginning a background task gains your app extended background execution time before it is suspended. Since the RunLoop will still be active a Timer or `asyncAfter` will still fire. You may be thinking of background fetch. 30 seconds is at the limit though, so 28 seconds delay might be safer

Comment: Could you maybe implement the timer in the peripheral instead and let it disconnect from the central after some time of inactivity?

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you provide some code snippet for the same.

Comment: @Emil - In BLE's central & peripheral concepts what I have understood that central never disconnect itself with peripheral. Let me correct, if I am wrong.

Comment: You're wrong. Any side can initiate disconnection.

Comment: @Emil OK. Is there any way to manage it from iOS Application side?